# What font is used on this Arnhem poster?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification, posters

I'm trying to make a poster for a class project, and I recently came across a poster that has this font.

[image]

It's a light, somewhat wide sans-serif typeface, but I'm not sure if it's Helvetica or Akzidenz or something similar.  Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: [Whatthefont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) can identify this.

Comment: @BillyKerr it didnt work very well

Comment: It looks like a thin/light member of the Neutra family

Comment: @superluminal it's pretty close, but not quite it.  The bowl on the R is too big on Neutra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is custom but it's very similar to ITC Avant Garde. Tip: reverse image searching an image often brings up information, as here.

Answer (score 6):

A reverse image search brings up the design archive this came from, as well as some details. 
It's CS Beta Bold  https://www.experimentaljetset.nl/archive/comingsoon

Judging from the details provided by the archive, you likely won't be able to obtain a license for this family.